# Fetching JSON data in protractor

Tags: json, protractor

I am doing protractor testing where a JSON data must be fetched to do a comparison. A part of JSONArray is shown below,

```
"ATA_Chapter": [
        {
          "@id": "01",
          "ATA_Chapter_Number": "Chapter 01",
          "ATA_Chapter_Title": "General Airplane Description"
        },
       {
          "@id": "02",
          "ATA_Chapter_Number": "Chapter 02",
          "ATA_Chapter_Title": "Communications"
        }]
```

I tried using below code,

```
console.log(json.Root.Catalog.ATA_Chapter[index].ATA_Chapter_Title);
```

In the console ,it is printing the values as,

```
General Airplane Description
Communications
```

but protractor is giving error as:

```
 Message:
   Failed: Cannot read property 'ATA_Chapter_Title' of undefined
```

Pls find the portion of spec code where above functionality is written

`var number;var title ;                                     console.log(json.Root.Catalog.ATA_Chapter[index].ATA_Chapter_Title);                   number = json.Root.Catalog.ATA_Chapter[index].ATA_Chapter_Number;                        title = json.Root.Catalog.ATA_Chapter[index].ATA_Chapter_Title;                              var chapterName = number+" "+title;                              element.all(by.repeater('chapter in chapters')).filter(function (ele,index) {                          return ele.getText().then(function(text){                                    console.log('text'+text); return text === chapterName; });                                      }).click();`

Comment: can you post your spec file?

Comment: can you please format your code not able to make anything out of this!

Comment: please update the question with the spec code.  Cannot read it in comments.

Comment: The issue is resolved..

Answer (score 1):

instead of trying to access the json in that way, I would suggest treating it as a module and exporting it like so:

```
module.exports= {
    "ATA_Chapter": [
        {
          "@id": "01",
          "ATA_Chapter_Number": "Chapter 01",
          "ATA_Chapter_Title": "General Airplane Description"
        },
       {
          "@id": "02",
          "ATA_Chapter_Number": "Chapter 02",
          "ATA_Chapter_Title": "Communications"
    }]
}
```

Then you include it in your spec file like so:

```
var ataData = require('path/to/your/json/file');

var number;var title

console.log(ataData.ATA_Chapter[index].ATA_Chapter_Title);

number = ataData.ATA_Chapter[index].ATA_Chapter_Number;
title = ataData.ATA_Chapter[index].ATA_Chapter_Title;
var chapterName = number+" "+title;
element.all(by.repeater('chapter in chapters')).filter(function (ele,index) {
    return ele.getText().then(function(text){
        console.log('text'+text);
        return text === chapterName;
    });
}).click();
```

This follows Angular/Protractor design patterns a little better and should help with undefined errors. Let me know if this works/helps!